# vscode sytax highlight breaks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlight is working funny. It's not working consistently.

picture:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5QrU.png![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5QrU.png!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq4yz.png)

In this picture, first function(bucketsize) is marked with yellow. However, at second and third function (even like def, return and any other syntax) highlighting stops, but! after few lines, it is working again, and then it breaks again.

Most important thing, this code works very well.

0. This happens at not just this code, but all other codes and new codes
1. I never touched source code
2. I was just making vitual environment, using venv
3. I changed file directory, folders to run on virtual environmnet
4. This happens with or without extention( eg.Material Theme )
5. This happens outside the virtual environment folder
6. I tried (erasing python, erasing vscode and all settings in it, even formating my computer) and still happening

Comment: I suspects a missing `(` or `:` in line 7. Show us your full code, as text!

Comment: @dona-py Is this the same when you are using other theme extensions? The syntax highlighting in VSCode is provided by the theme, (VSCode uses its own theme by default), and different themes present different highlighting. Also, try the disabled 'python for vscode' extension to check if it works.

Comment: Jill Cheng! Thanks! The probolem was extention ;) python for vscode. I never think the very basic extentions like 'python for vscode' might cause problem. Thanks again!